# Не выводятся в админке посты, добавленные через форму при помощи таксономии

Tags: wordpress

Есть форма отправки поста. Есть custom post type (cars) с таксономией (models).
Форма отправляет пост, но выводится он в общих записях!А нужно, чтоб выводился в custom post type. Где я тут что-то не учел?

functions.php:

```
function car_form_func($atts) {    

function insertData() {
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $new_post = array(
            'ID' => '',
            'post_content' => $_POST['content'] ,
            'post_title' => $_POST['title'],
            'post_status' => "Publish", // Publish Future Draft Pending Private Trash
            'post_taxmodels' => $_POST['models']
        );
        wp_insert_post($new_post);
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
add_action( 'insert_data_hook', 'insertData' ); 
do_action('insert_data_hook');
}
```

form.php:

```
<form name="test" method="post" action="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<h3>Name : <br>
    <input name="title" type="text" size="40">
</h3>

<?php
$categories = get_terms('taxmodels', 'orderby=name&hide_empty=0');
if($categories){
?>

<h3>Model: <br></h3>
    <select name="models">
        <?php foreach ($categories as $cat){ ?>
            <option value="{$cat->term_id}"><?php echo "{$cat->name}"?></option>";
        <?php  } ?>
    </select>
<?php } ?>

</br>
<h3>Description : <Br>
    <textarea name="content" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea></h3>
<p>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Отправить">
    <input nmame="clear" type="reset" value="Очистить"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно добавить строку в $new_post

```
'post_type' => 'cars'
```